# how to raise limit on record count returned by dns.resolve?

Tags: node.js, dns, amazon-route53

I have some node code that looks like this

```
dns.resolve( genericHostname, ( err, addresses ) => {
   console.log (addresses.count, 'dns records retrieved')
} )
```

In my environment this returns a maximum of 8 `addresses` records, even though there are more addresses than that registered in my DNS domain.  `dig` also returns only 8 addresses.

Why more than 8 addresses?  I'm using latency-based routing and have instances in various locations (AWS regions as it happens).

Why do I want them all in response to this `.resolve()` operation? To show a list of the servers in a web app?

It seems possible that my DNS answer record is bigger than a single UDP packet.

Is there any way to make node's built-in DNS resolver to return more than eight records? Can I force it to use TCP for the query?  Any other tricks?

Comment: "dig also returns only 8 addresses." Is the response truncated in any way? Did you try with `+tcp`? Did you try using the `edns` buffersize? If dig replies that, without a sign of truncation and even after having retried over TCP it really means this is all it got from the DNS server. So maybe the server is not always sending all the records (some servers can send different replies to different clients)

Comment: "It seems possible that my DNS answer record is bigger than a single UDP packet. " Normally in cases like that the responses come with the "truncation bit" set so that the client knows it did not get the full reply. In which case it can retry over TCP, and then it will get all the content. Some DNS libraries may be doing that automatically for you (but I have no idea about the one in NodeJS)

Comment: I don't see any issues when I test this, perhaps the limitation is on your DNS server side? What result do you get if you query `nodetest.bajic.nl`?

Comment: Bah! it looks like a limitation of the DNS server (AWS's)

Comment: My zone is also in Route53....

Comment: AWS limitation: https://www.amazonaws.cn/en/route53/faqs/#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20route,response%20to%20each%20DNS%20query.